# Overwriting CSS properties, a line-height issue

Tags: html, css, phpbb3

I made a layout for [www.phpbb.pl](http://phpbb.pl) and I want to apply the same layout for phpBB3 style.

I did that almost, but there is a difference in the footer. I think it's related with line-height and overwriting CSS properties from phpBB3 style. I tried to reset properties, but it doesn't help.I don't know how to go around it.

For css and html please look at [www.phpbb.pl](http://phpbb.pl) and [www.phpbb.pl/forum/](http://www.phpbb.pl/forum/) source code.

Images to compare:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Much more useful for you to post your CSS and what you tried to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#oberon_footer #oberon_left_side {
    float:left;
}
```

Needs to be

```
#oberon_footer #oberon_left_side {
    float:left;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

**Style.php line 3975** *(may not be the same in the source file)*

Comment: It is almost good, however now it looks like a problem with padding for the footer. However, it's the same in both ways :/.

Comment: @daroPL in any case... it looks almost identical... why does it have to be so precisely exactly the same?